# Kalman Filter for position : introducing acceleration estimates

Tags: filters, kalman-filters

I want to estimate the position on a 3D environment by introducing only acceleration estimates. Is that possible? If I use the extended Kalman Filter and introduce these estimates will I have the appropriate results?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: A Kalman filter is pretty meaningless unless you have multiple redundant inputs.  Otherwise it's just a fancy excuse for doing the obvious.  Could you describe your proposed system, or at least describe what you propose to use for inputs and what you want to get as outputs?